# Restarting sync service only

Tags: fredhopper

On multiple occasions now the sync service between our indexer and query instances has stopped and although it should recover gracefully, this doesn't happen always. Both `syncserver.log` and `syncclient.log` are full of errors. 
The query servers are working correctly so my question is:

Is there a way to just restart the sync service instead of restarting the instances? I couldn't find such information (both here and [Fredhopper Learning Center](https://www.fredhopper.com/learningcenter)) or have overlooked it.

We're using SmartTarget 2014SP1, FAS version 7.5.0.16 (107262), JRE version 1.7.0_40

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start the sync client through the deployment agent:

```
bin/deployment-agent-client invoke [instanceName] syncclient start
```

Same goes for every other process (qserver, xmlloader, etc.). They can all be managed through the deployment agent.